# How to import fernet_fields with PyInstaller on Mac

Tags: python, django, macos, encryption, pyinstaller

A working Django app fails to work with a NoneType object error during creation of a Company object in an app packaged with PyInstaller.

This Company model uses fernet fields (from the app django-fernet) to encrypt data. The save operation on this Company model causes the app to fail. Here's the model:

```
from fernet_fields import EncryptedCharField, EncryptedDateField, EncryptedTextField, EncryptedDateTimeField, EncryptedEmailField


class Company(models.Model):
    name = EncryptedCharField(max_length = 100, blank=False, verbose_name = "Nazwa")
    address = EncryptedTextField(blank=False, verbose_name="Adres firmy")
    per_hour = EncryptedFloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Stawka/h", validators = [MinValueValidator(0.1), MaxValueValidator(999)])
    cost_per_patient = EncryptedFloatField( blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Koszt/pacjenta", validators = [MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(999)])
    cost_per_month = EncryptedFloatField( blank=True,null=True, verbose_name="Stałe miesięczne koszty", validators = [MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99999)])
    renting_fee = EncryptedFloatField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Stały koszt wynajmu gabinetu")
    they_pay = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name="Płatność pacjenta za odwołane")
    me_pay = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name="Płatność moja za odwołane")
    other_payments = models.ManyToManyField(OtherPayments, blank=True, verbose_name = "Inne płatności")
    created = models.DateField(editable=False)
```

I assume the error is connected to the fact that django-fernet (fernet_fields) is not loaded correctly for the PyInstaller compilation process. I can see that from the error-log:

```
missing module named fernet_fields.EncryptedField - imported by fernet_fields, terapeuta.models
missing module named fernet_fields.EncryptedEmailField - imported by fernet_fields, terapeuta.models
missing module named fernet_fields.EncryptedDateField - imported by fernet_fields, terapeuta.models
missing module named fernet_fields.EncryptedDateTimeField - imported by fernet_fields, terapeuta.models
missing module named fernet_fields.EncryptedCharField - imported by fernet_fields, terapeuta.models
missing module named fernet_fields.EncryptedTextField - imported by fernet_fields, terapeuta.models
```

I'm trying to import fernet_fields into PyInstaller spec file like this:

```
import sys 


sys.path.insert(0,"/Users/karol/virtualenv/venv_zapiszsesje/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fernet_fields")
```

I have also added it to `hiddenimports=['fernet_fields']` and this is still not working.

How to add fernet_fields into the spec file such that fernet_fields gets also packaged?

Comment: Try adding `fernet_fields.EncryptedField` to the hidden imports. If it doesn't show in the error messages then you need to add all the modules separately. A cleaner way is to create a hook and use the`collect_submodules` function as described [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html#useful-items-in-pyinstaller-utils-hooks).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried it and added 'fernet_fields.EncryptedField' and all the others into 'hidden_imports'. Unfortunately PyInstaller tells me 'Hidden import: fernet_fields.EncryptedField not found'... There must be something wrong with Pythonpath, or something else ...